# What is the GB size and time to sync for geth in september 2018

Tags: go-ethereum, fast-sync

How long does it take? What is the Size?

Answer (score 2):

On september 24th 2018, fast sync came in at just over 135 GB, with --cache 1024.

It took a 2017 Macbook pro about 18 hours to sync up.